# Combining duplicate table entries across tables with more than 2 columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to archive all of my Yugioh cards in an Excel Workbook. I have a dozen decks and upward of 1500 singles, so I thought it would be handy to have a reference of all of them. What I have so far in my excel workbook is a unique worksheet for each deck, formatted into a table like so:

| **Card Name** | **Category** | **No.** | **Game** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mezuki | Monster/Effect | 3 | Yu-Gi-Oh |
| Gozuki | Monster/Effect | 3 | Yu-Gi-Oh |
| Foolish Burial | Spell | 1 | Yu-Gi-Oh |

What I want to do is have a master table of all the cards I own that includes all the cards from my assembled decks and all the loose singles I own. "Foolish Burial" is a good example of where I am having trouble. I use that card in several decks and I have a few spares. What I want is for my master table to count all the copies of the card, across all my decks and loose singles and add them together.

Initially I tried using Power Query. I Googled and followed some instructions and ended up with this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] <> "Rayquaza_deck")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"Card Name", "Category", "No.", "Game"}, {"Card Name", "Category", "No.", "Game"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Content",{"Name"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

The specific reference to "Rayquaza_deck" is a temporary workaround to avoid recursion. I unselected one of the tables so that the "select all" option was not selected. This grabbed all the entries from each of the tables in the worksheets and placed them on top of each other into a single table. The reference to "removed columns" is because initially the new combined table had an extra column listing which table each row came from. I didn't want this, so I fiddled around until it didn't appear anymore. However, it duplicated identical entries. So there would be several rows for "Foolish Burial" for example. I figure, well, at least I have a big table of everything, Excel has a shiny button labelled "consolidate" so I tried that, and it worked, but only sort of. It did combine the duplicate rows and correctly summed the number of each card I have. However, The "Category" and "Game" columns were empty. Additionally the "Card Name" column header didn't appear.

My specific question is this: How do I combine all of the tables that are my assembled decks and loose singles into a master table that combines duplicates by summing the total number of any card?

I Have some experience using Excel functions, but none with Visual Basic that Google seemed to suggest, and none with Power Query outside of what is here.

Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cjj21I1HMZYc4QKW9LdS9QqesxXXYtjG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues

- Your PQ does not include "Singles"

  - Make Singles a table.
  - Column Headers in Singles table are not the same as the others (Name vs Card Name)

    - You can change it on the table, or within the Power Query.
- Make line 3 something like:

  ```
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] <> "Query1")),
  ```
- I think you know you want to use `GroupBy` on the card name, and `Count Rows` for the operation
- Your particular problem with **Foolish Burial** is that one of the entries has a trailing space.

  - So do a Transform/Trim on columns you want to GroupBy.
- I don't know if there are other issues, like case, that you may also have to check for.

If you have other issues, please be as specific as you can.

***Note:***

I think an ideal grouping method for your issue would be `Table.FuzzyGroup`. Unfortunately, although it seems to be present, it does not work (at least not in my version of O365 Excel).

In my example, I first change the name of the first column on the Singles sheet from `Name` to `Card Name` to make it the same as the others.

To mimic some of the fuzzy options, I chose to create a custom column for grouping where, with regard to the `Card Name`, I made it all lower case, and removed all spaces.

Then I grouped on that column with aggregations for Count (sum of the No. column), and for All Rows.

Then extracted the originals.

```
let 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),

    //Remove Query1 table -- the results
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] <> "Query1")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"Card Name", "Category", "No.", "Game"}, {"Card Name", "Category", "No.", "Game"}),

    //Select only those rows where the Game is Yu-Gi-Oh
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Content", each ([Game] = "Yu-Gi-Oh")),

    //Type the columns (note need Text type for next step
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Card Name", type text}, {"Category", type text}, {"No.", Int64.Type}, {"Game", type text}, {"Name", type text}}),

    //Lower case and remove spaces for grouping column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "groupON", 
                            each Text.Lower(
                                Text.Remove([Card Name]," "))),

    //Count the number of cards by summing the No. Column
    //Also group with All Rows so as to extract original card name and Category
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"groupON"}, {{"Count", 
                            each List.Sum([#"No."]), type nullable number}, 
                                {"Grouped", each _, type table [Card Name=nullable text, Category=nullable text, #"No."=nullable number, Game=nullable text, Name=nullable text, groupON=text]}}),

    //extract original Card Name       
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Card Name", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Card Name"){0}),

    //extract original Category
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Category", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Category"){0}),

    //Remove unwanted columns and reorder results
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"groupON", "Grouped"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Card Name", "Category", "Count"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

**Results**

[image]

**Foolish Burial** filter:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help!
The singles aren't in a table because that list is out of date. I will have to go back through my collection and recount everything. I just wanted to get started on a system that I could hopefully plug the Singles table into once it was ready. I didn't realise the column headers were different on the singles sheet. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I notice that the master table this code produces will only output Yu-Gi-Oh cards. I'd like to also include the Pokemon cards, and be flexible to allow for other card games as my obsession grows hahah. If I delete the line of code that specifically references selecting for Yu-Gi-Oh in the Game column, will that include all the games?
Otherwise, your solution is perfect! The Foolish Burial example seems to demonstrate this does exactly what I'd like it to. Thanks again!

Comment: @FluffyHoodie You did write in your question that you wanted to *archive all of my Yugioh cards*. What happened when you tried deleting the step that selects just the Yugioh cards?  Did you delete it from the code? or from the Applied Steps window?